# Increasing subline-number in verse without starting a new line

Tags: reledmac

In the following example I would like to be able to print the critical footnote as 33c instead of 33b. Verses in longer metres I would normally typeset in four lines, but here the metre is only of eight syllables per verse quarter, such that it normally two feet are typeset in one line. Would it be possible to increase the subline counter at a specific place without inserting an actual line break? Or, if that should not be possible, replace the automatically generated number by one manually specified? I tried the latter with `\linenum{}`, but without success.

```
\documentclass[article]{memoir}
\usepackage{reledmac}
\setlength{\stanzaindentbase}{\leftmargin}
\setstanzaindents{4,1,2,1,2,3,3,1,2,1}
\setstanzapenalties{1,10000,5000,10000,0}
\numberstanzatrue
\renewcommand{\stanzanumwrapper}[1]{}
\newcounter{stanzanum}
\Xstanza
\Xstanzaseparator[A]{.}
\Xstanzaseparator[B]{}
\Xstanzaseparator[C]{.}
\Xstanzaseparator[D]{.}

\Xarrangement[]{paragraph}
\begin{document}
\setcounter{stanza}{32}
\beginnumbering
\setcounter{firstlinenum}{1000}
\linenumberstyle{alph}
{\large %
\stanza
śaktir nītyā nayo lakṣmyā lakṣmīr maitryā guṇair asau |&
\edtext{ta ātmanātmā}{\Bfootnote{MH07; te cātmanātmā GS.}} buddhyāsau te dhīr vācānugamyate || 33 ||\&
}
\endnumbering
\end{document}
```

Comment: I second @henryflower's answer. It is an organic solution by which you effectively change the (sub-)line number in the main text, *and*, as a consequence, the footnote numbering. `\linenum{}` is also a good idea, if you're OK with changing *only* the numbering *printed* in the footnote. Here's how I would use it: `\edtext{main text}{\linenum{33|3||33|3}\Bfootnote{footnote}}` Does this work for you? ("3" is for subline "c".)

Comment: Yes, `\linenum{33|3||33|3}` works, but `\advanceline{1}` is indeed much more straightforward.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`reledmac` provides the `\advanceline` command for this. Section 5.4.3 (setting and changing line number) in my `reledmac` documentation: "The `\setline{<num>}` and `\advanceline{<num>}` commands may be used to change the current line's number (or the sub-line number, if sub-lineation is currently on). [...] `\advanceline` takes one argument, an amount that should be added to the current line number; it may be positive or negative."

So `\advanceline{1}` before your `\edtext` will provide the desired shift to 33c.